# theme_radios working but theme_radio is not

Tags: 7, theming

Hello I am trying to figure it out what's causing theme_radio not to work. It is Drupal 7 and this is my code:

```
// Hook Theme in my module
function MY_MODULE_theme(){
    return array(        
        'MY_MODULE_radios' => array(
          'render element' => 'element',
          'variables' => NULL,
        ),
        'MY_MODULE_radio' => array(
          'render element' => 'element',
          'variables' => NULL,
        ),
    );
}
```

My implementations of the themes are Drupal standard still since I am trying to get them to work  first, the XDebug does stop at the breakpoint in theme_MY_MODULE_radios but not in theme_MY_MODULE_radio:

```
function theme_MY_MODULE_radios($variables) {  
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $attributes = array();
  if (isset($element['#id'])) {
    $attributes['id'] = $element['#id'];
  }
  $attributes['class'] = 'form-radios';
  if (!empty($element['#attributes']['class'])) {
    $attributes['class'] .= ' ' . implode(' ', $element['#attributes']['class']);
  }
  if (isset($element['#attributes']['title'])) {
    $attributes['title'] = $element['#attributes']['title'];
  }
  return '<div' . drupal_attributes($attributes) . '>' . (!empty($element['#children']) ? $element['#children'] : '') . '</div>';
}

function theme_MY_MODULE_radio($variables) {
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $element['#attributes']['type'] = 'radio';
  element_set_attributes($element, array('id', 'name', '#return_value' => 'value'));

  if (isset($element['#return_value']) && $element['#value'] !== FALSE && $element['#value'] == $element['#return_value']) {
    $element['#attributes']['checked'] = 'checked';
  }
  _form_set_class($element, array('form-radio'));

  return '<div>Hello - </div><input' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . ' />';
}
```

And this is how my form element looks like:

```
**************** Rest of Form *************
  $form['comment_preview'] = array(
    '#type' => 'radios',
    '#title' => t('Preview comment'),
    '#options' => array(
      1 => t('Yes'),
      0 => t('No'),
    ),
    '#theme' => 'MY_MODULE_radios',
    '#theme_wrapper' => array(),
  );
**************** Rest of Form *************
```

Why is `theme_MY_MODULE_radio()` never called?

Comment: The difference is that the _radio_ type already has a theme, while the _radios_ type doesn't. See [`system_element_info()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.module/function/system_element_info/7.x).

Comment: Okay but why it is not picking the new theme though. Do I need to override it? Not really understanding how the fact that one of them already have a theme is changing anything here.

Comment: Probably Drupal is using the one defined in that hook, not your theme function.

Comment: By the way, what do you mean by _doesn't work_?

Comment: Code in theme_radio is never executed, while the one in theme_radios is.

Comment: What I don't really understand is why theme is now used at all since it follows the naming convention: theme_MY_MODULE_radio.